# Tornado , send message periodically

Tags: python, tornado

I have a simple tornado server.

```
class MyWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)

if __name__ == 'main':
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MyWebSocket),
    ])
    application.listen(3333)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I would like to have a timed event, that sends a message to the connected client every 10 seconds or so. Is there a way to have a timed event do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSocket Server sending messages periodically in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542333/websocket-server-sending-messages-periodically-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Tornado's PeriodicCallback? Allows you to schedule a function to be called with a given interval.

See the [Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=periodiccallback#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback).

Comment: put an example here please doc is vague and contains no example and your URL could be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the add_timeout method on the IOloop to create a callback every ten seconds. Example below.

```
class MyWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)
        self.send_and_schedule_next(message)

    def send_and_schedule_next(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(
            time.time() + 10, 
            self.send_and_schedule_next(message)
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

This answers has a simple example  of `PeriodicCallback` along with `websockets`.

[WebSocket Server sending messages periodically in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542333/websocket-server-sending-messages-periodically-in-python/19571205#19571205)